# Problems traversing through definition list by index

Tags: jquery

I have a definition list containing the 12 months of the year. I have 3 months showing at a time for example (January, February, March). My goal is to have the list advance to the next month when the last child is clicked. For example when March is clicked, April will appear and January would disappear showing (February, March, and April), so on and so forth.

Here's my HTML

```
<div id="archive" class="archive">
    <div>Archive</div>
    <dl>
        <dt>January</dt>
        <dt>February</dt>
        <dt>March</dt>
        <dt>April</dt>
        <dt>May</dt>
        <dt>June</dt>
        <dt>July</dt>
        <dt>August</dt>
        <dt>September</dt>
        <dt>October</dt>
        <dt>November</dt>
        <dt>December</dt>
    </dl>
</div>
```

and here's the jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#archive dl dt:gt(2)").hide();

$("#archive dl dt").each(function(index, value) {
        $(this).click(function() {
            if ($("#archive dl dt:visible").size() == (index + 1)) {
                $(this).next("dt").show(500);
                $("#archive dl dt:eq(" + (index - 2) + ")").hide(500);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and I also have a jfiddle link:
[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jdwalker/y5ngh/2/)

The problem I'm having is that it only works once. When April is clicked, nothing happens. I don't get any errors on the debugging console either.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just change the `if()` statement to check if the `.next('dt')` element `.is(':hidden')`.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/y5ngh/3/

```
if ($(this).next("dt").is(':hidden')) {
    $(this).next("dt").show(500);
    $("#archive dl dt:eq(" + (index - 2) + ")").hide(500);
}
```

Here's the full version that goes both directions. It can be simplified a bit, but this works.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/y5ngh/5/

```
$("#archive dl dt").each(function(index, value) {
    $(this).click(function() {
        if ($(this).next("dt").is(':hidden')) {
            $(this).next("dt").show(500);
            $("#archive dl dt:eq(" + (index - 2) + ")").hide(500);
        } else if ($(this).prev("dt").is(':hidden')) {
            $(this).prev("dt").show(500);
            $("#archive dl dt:eq(" + (index + 2) + ")").hide(500);
        }
    });
});
```

---

Updated version that reduces selection & redundancy: http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/y5ngh/11/

```
$("#archive dl dt").click(function() {
    var $th = $(this), dir = ['next', 'prev'];
    if ($th.prev("dt").is(':hidden')) dir.reverse();
    else if ($th.next("dt").is(':visible')) return;
    $th[dir[0]]("dt").show(500)[dir[1] + 'Until'](':hidden').last().hide(500);
}).slice( 3 ).hide();
```

Comment: scope out my answer, no need to iterate through

Answer (score 2):

This can be simplified a lot, just use `next()` and `prev()`

```
$("#archive dl dt:gt(2)").hide();

// we'll use not(":last") so that December can't be clicked
$("#archive dl dt").not(":last").each(function(index, value) {
    $(this).click(function() {
            $(this).next().show(500);
            $(this).prev().prev().hide(500);
    });
});
```

[**Try it here**](http://jsfiddle.net/y5ngh/4/)

Comment: Good answer (+1). Only minor problem is that you can click on "December" and just remove "October" which I don't think is his intent. I added a quick check for that.

Comment: Thanks @JasCav, you're absolutely right :) I've added a `not(":last")` to the `.each` selector to ensure the click isn't assigned to the last element.

Comment: Ooo...nicer solution. Thanks for that. I know how to get stuff done in jQuery, but it's not always the prettiest. I always like learning better ways of using it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use This one

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $("#archive dl dt:gt(2)").hide();
    $("#archive dl dt").click
    (
            function()
            {
                $("#archive dl dt").hide();
                if($(this).next()!=null && $(this).next().length!=0 && $(this).next().next()!=null && $(this).next().next().length!=0)
                {
                    $(this).next().show();
                    $(this).next().next().show();
                }
             }
    );
});
```

Comment: Wow talk about overengineering :)